# My compiler tells me it cannot convert 'void' to 'string' I understand what this means, but not how to fix it

Tags: c#, string, random, instantiation, void

Here I am trying to instantiate the defined `GameObject` at random positions (defined in `RandomPosOne()`)

But my compiler says

> cannot convert from 'void' to 'string'

```
public class Enemyspawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Elf;
 
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("SpawnTrigger1"))
        {
            InvokeRepeating((SpawnElfOne()), 2f, 3f);

        }
        void SpawnElfOne()
        {
            Instantiate(Elf, RandomPosOne(), Quaternion.identity);
        }
        
    }

    Vector2 RandomPosOne()
    {
        float x, y;
        x = Random.Range(-8.6f, 8.7f);
        y = Random.Range(3.05f, -3.36f);
        return new Vector2(x, y);
    }

    Vector2 RandomPosTwo()
    {
        float x, y;
        x = Random.Range(-8.8f, 8.8f);
        y = Random.Range(19f, 12.6f);
        return new Vector2(x, y);
    }

}
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the local void method `SpawnElfOne` out into the instance

and pass the target method name as a `string` parameter when invoking `InvokeRepeating`

```
public class Enemyspawner : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject Elf;
 
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collider) {
        if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("SpawnTrigger1")) {
            InvokeRepeating("SpawnElfOne", 2f, 3f);
        }           
    }

    void SpawnElfOne() {
        Instantiate(Elf, RandomPosOne(), Quaternion.identity);
    }
        
    Vector2 RandomPosOne() {
        float x, y;
        x = Random.Range(-8.6f, 8.7f);
        y = Random.Range(3.05f, -3.36f);
        return new Vector2(x, y);
    }

    Vector2 RandomPosTwo() {
        float x, y;
        x = Random.Range(-8.8f, 8.8f);
        y = Random.Range(19f, 12.6f);
        return new Vector2(x, y);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `nameof(SpawnElfOne)` be preferable here?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes that works as well. Wasn't sure what version of C# OP was using so did not want to make any assumptions.

Comment: Thanks, that works great, the error in compiling that script caused every other script in the project to stop working so you've saved me a lot of pain.